# Counting based on 2 Arrays with Null Values

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have two arrays of data I am trying to count. One array is all text(Source column) and the other is all dates (date ticket closed) represented as 1-Jan for January 1st.

What I am trying to do is count how many containing a source, but no date (signifying that the ticket is still open).

I have tried many different formulas and each one returns an error. I think the 2 closed I've got are:

(I also had one that replaced COUNTA with both COUNTIF and it still did not work properly.)

```
=COUNTIF('Help Desk Log'!B2:B, "Internal") - COUNTIF('Help Desk Log'!K2:K,"="&" " )
```

and

```
=IF(AND('Help Desk Log'!B2:B = "Internal", 'Help Desk Log'!K2:K - " "), COUNTA('Help Desk Log'!J2:J) - COUNTA(ISTEXT('Help Desk Log'!K2:K)))


 Source            Date
External        1-Jan
Internal        (Null)
Internal        1-Jan
External        2-Jan
Internal        2-Jan
Internal        (Null)
Internal        (Null)
Internal        4-Jan
```

Both return a #NAME? error.

I am not sure what to change to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS('Help Desk Log'!B:B, "Internal",'Help Desk Log'!K:K,"=")
```

Comment: I still get the #NAME? error with that one. I also tried that with "=" " " and "="& " ". With the first equation I had a version of it where the second CountIF had a IsText( within it to convert the date to a text, but still returned an error.

Comment: @Smithw1 see edit.  I missed that you were not using the range correctly.  Excel does not accept `B2:B` as a valid reference.  Change it to the full column.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I had a feeling i was overlooking something. The errors I received pointed to the equation itself. I was not thinking of the range. All of the sources I found about counting null values were about the nomenclature for "=" or "="&" " kind of stuff.